# datatables showing row from query with � in áéíóúÑ

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I get ready with DataTables for make a nice table with `JQuery` and `html`.

But when query to my `db` it show me values like this in this characters cases (almost).

```
(Spanish letters) áéíóúÑ
```

Any suggestions.

ADDED DATATABLE CODE USED:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  // Localization
  language : {
    emptyTable     : 'Nada para mostrar.',
    zeroRecords    : 'Nada coincide.',
    thousands      : '.',
    processing     : 'Cargando informacion...',
    loadingRecords : 'Cargando Informacion...',
    info           : ' _PAGE_ / _PAGES_',
    infoEmpty      : ' 0 / 0',
    infoFiltered   : '( _MAX_ )',
    infoPostFix    : '',
    lengthMenu     : 'Mostrando _MENU_',
    search         : 'Filtrar:',
    paginate       : {
      first    : 'Primero',
      last     : 'Ultimo',
      next     : 'Siguiente',
      previous : 'Previo'
    }
  }
});jquery
```

Comment: Character encoding on server side (keywords for the SO search or Google) -- There is the database charset and the HTML charset.... UTF-8 works fine for the produced page... and the "backend" which is the DB, `latin1_swedish_ci` or `utf8_general_ci` works fine.

Comment: Hi Louis thanks for you very-fast reply.
This only happen on queries processed on javascript side by Datatables.
I make a  test without dataTables the characters show normally

Comment: Okay... So you are fine to `echo` the data with the correct characters? (like in a `<div>`)

Comment: yes, only happen in DataTable View,  in </div> is fine.

Comment: Ok... So post the code where you instantiate Datatables and a data sample (1 line).

Comment: set your database collation into utf8

Comment: i add the code now!

Comment: Ok... A quick test... Remove all those language options. Does the problem persist? Just : `var table = $('#example').DataTable();` and re-run the page (be sure to ignore cache with [CTRL]+[F5])

Comment: the `database` already have the  `utf8_spanish_ci` collation

Comment: the test give me the same result.

Comment: Okay... So it's **NOT** the DataTables plugin nor jQuery. -- That's a debugging step made. ;)  I found you an [**exhaustive page**](https://xaviesteve.com/1223/issues-with-accents-and-strange-characters-in-php-mysql-solved/) to read for more.

Comment: i go to your link rigth now, and make a jsfidlle but my database will not be accesed by others

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: mmm... You could create a PHP page that accesses the DB with this PHP header: ` <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>` and [**Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it on JsFiddle. But that's some more to learn just to reproduce the issue... But not bad at all to learn.

Comment: Based on this [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php), try this: `echo mb_internal_encoding();` (in a div in the page...)

Comment: this is really nice... you recommend me make a fork? **http://jsfiddle.net/1tg324k0/**

Comment: I don't get those last 2 comments. But what I can say is keep on trying. Your last Fiddle looks llike an example cut and paste. --- I'm close to mark your question as «Too broad».

Comment: This php header `header header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");` added to php  code change and shows the DataTable correctly,  but the others chars outside dataTables like áéíóúÑ shows wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem radicate on the PDO call.

I wrongly use for mistake two differents calls, one of the not using the utf8 correct configuration on the call like this

```
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHost.";dbname=".DBName."", DBUser, DBPassword);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch(PDOException $e){

      die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());

   }
```

And finally when add the CORRECT utf-8 configuration all characters showing good.

```
 try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $this->DBName . ';host=' . $this->Host . ';port=' . $this->DBPort . ';charset=utf8', 
            $this->DBUser, 
            $this->DBPassword,
            array(
                //For PHP 5.3.6 or lower
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                //
                //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,

                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
            )
        );

    } catch(PDOException $e){

      die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());

   }
```

The last code solved the problem.
Thanks!